# How can i write a variabile in the Function Console.Write in this case?

Tags: c#

I am learning c# for fun!
I have experience with the c coding and I have a really stupid question, in my console application, I want to show a variable called "x" using Console.Write but I want to show it with also a text line in the same function. If you don't understand I attach here the code that i did.

```
  using System;

namespace Media_Random
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write ("This program makes an avarage of 3 numbers chosen randomly\n");
            int a = 1;
            int b = 10;
            Random random = new Random();
            int x=random.Next(a,b);
            Console.Write ("the first value is\n",x); //i want to in write in the console the value x there but it doesn't work 
        }
    }
```

}

I hope that showing the code it will be more simple to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Console.Write("the first value is {0}\n", x);
```

Please, notice that the overloaded [Console.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdyw6yk(v=vs.110).aspx) you've used wants *format string* with *placeholder* for `x`: `{0}` in the context.

Further suggestion: `Console` has as special method `WriteLine` that's why you, probably, don't want put

```
 Console.Write("...\n");
```

instead of

```
 Console.WriteLine("...");
```

Comment: Ok that's work so for example if I want to show multiple variables I have to do this :
 Console.Write("the first value is {0}{1}{2} \n",x,y,z);

Comment: @mikiIN8bit: quite right: do as you've put it:  `Console.Write("the first value is {0} {1} {2} \n",x,y,z);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this to display it in this format :

```
the first value is
X
```

Then use this method :

```
Console.Write(string.Format("the first value is\n{0}", x));
```

But if you prefer to display int in this format :

```
the first value is X
<newlinehere>
```

Then use this method :

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("the first value is {0}\n', x));
```

You should [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to format it in the different way.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing. If you are using VS 2015 you can change string.Format with $ like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"the first value is {x}");
```

Adding $ in front of the open quotes allows you to put the variables inside the placeholders directly. From my point of view this syntax is much more easier and more readable.